# How does halacha treat "psychological damage"?

Tags: torts-damages, psych-mentalhealth

Is "psychological damage" a notion that is accepted in Jewish law -- that is, the notion that, beyond physical harm, financial cost, loss of income, etc., there is damage to mental health?

The Mishna [Baba Kamma 83b] tells us that one who injures another becomes liable for five things:  damages, pain, medical expenses, loss of livelihood, and mental anguish (sometimes translated as humiliation or indignity): מתני׳ החובל בחבירו חייב עליו משום חמשה דברים בנזק בצער בריפוי בשבת ובושת.

How, exactly, is that last one interpreted in halacha?  Examples?  The Mishna appears to begin with a physical injury ("one who injures another").  Is that the case (that is, if the offender is only guilty of stealing, does the mishna apply)?

Comment: +1 But the answer is it doesn't. I remember when I was a kid learning Bava Kamma for the first time it bothered me that when you kill someone's most precious favorite pet cow all you pay him back is the value of a cow.

Comment: You were taught that injuring someone includes actions that do no physical harm to him?  That was part of my question.

Comment: What? I was taught, as per the Talmud, that mental anguish plays no part in compensation. Whether it is direct physical harm to their person or possessions.

Comment: *Boshes* (embarrasment) is one of the categories of damage that must be reimbursed. Also the cost of healing the damage to mental health would be counted as medical expenses.

Comment: @sabahillel Boshes is a very specific point, but a good one nonetheless, more of a question than an answer really. Your claim about the cost of healing mental health would need a source more noteworthy than your comment.